Ocelot using Signalr, web request 404
I used Signalr in Ocelot and the web page showed a 404 Not Found when sending a connection request.
My configuration looks like this:
{
    "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "DELETE",
        "OPTIONS"
    ],
    "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/GatewayHub/{catchAll}",
    "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{catchAll}",
    "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
    "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
            "Host": "127.0.0.1",
            "Port": 9933
        }
    ],
    "LoadBalancerOptions": {
        "Type": "RoundRobin"
    },
    "HttpHandlerOptions": {
        "UseProxy": true,
        "UseCookies": true,
        "AllowAutoRedirect": false
    }
}



Result of web page request:


Specifications
Version: 23.3.3
Platform: .NET6
Subsystem: Windows 10
How to solve this problem.

Hi, please try to enable the signalr client/server side logging first, then we can find more about this issue.

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.
